# TensorFlow: logits and labels must have the same first dimension while using loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

I am using TensorFlow to perform classification on my data.

Sample data are as follow:

```
Sentence                                   Score
-------------------------------------------------
I am a boy.                                5
I am a monster.                            1
```

The score has range from 1 to 5.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
print(df.info())
```

prints:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 13743 entries, 0 to 13742
Data columns (total 8 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------        --------------  -----  
 0   Sentence      13743 non-null  object 
 1   Score         1316 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 859.1+ KB
None
```

and here are the remaining codes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.utils import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, LSTM, SpatialDropout1D
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.layers import Dropout
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import word_tokenize
STOPWORDS = set(stopwords.words('english'))
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from chart_studio import plotly
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = 'all'
from plotly.offline import iplot
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()
cf.set_config_file(offline=False, world_readable=True)

df['score'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).iplot(kind='bar', yTitle='Number of Sentences', 
                                                                title='Number of Sentences in each score')
```

(the plot is here)

```
# LSTM Modeling

# The maximum number of words to be used. (most frequent)
MAX_NB_WORDS = 50000
# Max number of words in each complaint.
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 250
# This is fixed.
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_NB_WORDS, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~', lower=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df['yue'].values)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print('Found %s unique tokens.' % len(word_index))
```

```
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df['yue'].values)
X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
print('Shape of data tensor:', X.shape)

# Shape of data tensor: (13743, 250)

Y = pd.get_dummies(df['score']).values
print('Shape of label tensor:', Y.shape)

# Shape of label tensor: (13743, 5)

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size = 0.10, random_state = 42)
print(X_train.shape,Y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape,Y_test.shape)

# (12368, 250) (12368, 5)
# (1375, 250) (1375, 5)

num_classes = 5

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=X.shape[1]))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs = 5
batch_size = 64

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,validation_split=0.1,callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3, min_delta=0.0001)])
```

and it results this error:

```
Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [64,5] and labels shape [320]
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_14466]
```

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: You can try using `loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'`

Comment: it works, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` expects labels in the form of integers which denotes the class indices. Instead, you are providing the labels/targets in the form of one-hot-encoded values. Hence, even though the shape of your `label` for one batch (=64) is `[64,5]`, it is being reshaped to `64 x 5 = [320]` inherently within the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, which leads to a dimension mismatch.

The right choice of loss here would be `categorical_crossentropy` which performs the same calculation except this one takes labels/targets in one-hot-encoded form.

Replace this line in your code:

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

with the following:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and it should work.

I recommend reading the official docs from Keras about [Categorical Crossentropy](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#categoricalcrossentropy-class) and [Sparse Categorical Crossentropy](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#sparsecategoricalcrossentropy-class) for further reference.